# Finding Distinct Roots of Polynomial equation

Tags: calculus

Let  $a\in R$ and let  $f : R→ R$,  be given by $f (x) = x^5 – 5x + a$. Find the domain of 'a' if f(x) has A) One root B) More than one root
These are my steps
$$f'(x)=5x^4-5=5(x-1)(x-(-1))(x^2+1)$$
For Decreasing function $x\in (-1,1)$

For increasing function  $x\in (-\infty,-1)$ & $x\in (1,\infty)$

As there are two point where f'(x) vanishes hence f(x) has three roots 
After this step I am struck as question deals with range of 'a'

Comment: @Robert Z As you helped me in previous problem, I used the same logic but it has two points where f'(x) vanishes so can you help me after these sreps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $$f'(x)=5x^4-5=5(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)$$ and $$f''(x)=20x^3$$

Comment: Your derivatives are wrong

Comment: thank you for your hint!